# Creating a bookmarklet that always fetches latest external script version and keeps it in cache?

Tags: javascript, cache-control, browser-cache

With in-page script tags I normally do:

```
script src="js/all.2011_02_02.js"
```

That way the browser fetches the latest version when I update the script source url and keeps it in cache.

Well, how can I accomplish that with **a bookmarklet** which *I can´t edit* (unless I ask the user to delete/create new)?

sample bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://example.com/js/all.js;})()
```

Comment: What would be the point of something like that?

Comment: @Pointy I want a bookmarklet that I never need to change(by loading the script externally) but still has that latest external script cached for responsiveness. Do you mean that the browser don´t cache that external script?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

But you can do

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://example.com/js/all.js?'+new Date().getTime();})()
```

if you do not want the script cached at all

Comment: Hm, I´ll be serving quite some kB, often and a lot. Maybe some server-side magic?

Comment: Of course. You can proxy it, do a HEAD, save it on your server and check the date